# ImportError: import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma [ PYTHON on datalab]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-analysis

I would like to add model analysis to my model but was unable to import the libraries:

I am using datalab environment.

```
import tensorflow as tf
!pip install tensorflow_model_analysis
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
```

The error is:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f85e4d8fbd99> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 
---> 17 from tensorflow_model_analysis import view
     18 from tensorflow_model_analysis.api import tfma_unit as test
     19 from tensorflow_model_analysis.api.model_eval_lib import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

ImportError: cannot import name view
```

Please advice what will be the right way to import the library.

Thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 1):

Working for me now with the following installation:

```
python 2.7 - to support apache beam
pip install pip==9.0.3  # I am not sure what is the reason, but essential for apache beam pipelines execution
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-model-analysis
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
```